# How can I provide a password to openssl enc in a bash script?

Tags: bash, openssl

i have a bash script to dump mysql and making tar and protect it with openssl

```
tar -cf ${DB}_${DATE}.tar *.sql | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -e > ${DB}_${DATE}.tar.gz.enc  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

but my bash script will stop because of ask password
how can i fill the passwords in bash script ?

Comment: Have you looked at the help to `openssl enc`? It tells you how to specify where to read the password from.

Comment: btw, your file _isn't_ a gzip file; it's just a tarball; you're putting a `.gz` in the filename, but that name is incorrect/misleading. If you _want_ it to be gzipped before encryption, change `tar -cf` to `tar -czf`.

Comment: BTW, in `>file >/dev/null 2>&1`, the `>/dev/null` overrides the `>file`, so your file ends up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the manual tells you, `-pass source` specifies a location from which openssl will read the password to use.

Assuming this is a bash script instead of a sh script, you can use [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
tar -czf "${DB}_${DATE}.tar" *.sql |
  openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -e -pass file:<(echo "password") \
  >"${DB}_${DATE}.tar.gz.enc" 2>/dev/null
```

Note that redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` is a bad idea -- I'm doing it because it's what your original code did, but it makes it impossible to troubleshoot failures.